# UWP - Is there any way to change the mouse cursor when exiting ListView without the event being triggered during drag and drop?

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a draggable ListView that changes the mouse cursor on PointerEntered, PointerPressed and DragItemsStarting events. The problem is every time I perform drag and drop I always trigger PointerExited which resets the cursor back to arrow.

If it is impossible to not trigger PointerExited, what other ways can I do to reset the cursor back to arrow when exiting the Listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can judge the event itself when the `PointerExited` event is triggered.

`PointerExited` is indeed triggered when you drag the `ListViewItem`, but `PointerRoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource` is different from moving the pointer normally. This is the basis of our judgment.

Try this:

```cs
private void ListView_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.OriginalSource is ListViewItemPresenter)
    {
        return;
    }
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Arrow, 0);
}
```

When dragging, the source that triggers the `PointerExited` event is `ListViewItemPresenter`. Through this judgment, Cursor can work as expected.

Best regards.